# How do I add image to drawable in android studio?

Tags: android

I want to add `Button` icon in the `drawable` resource folder.
To do this I tried to add the `png` icon as Image Asset but when I choose **Action Bar and Tab Icon** from the **Asset Type** dropdown list I find the image is not clear and if I returned to the **Luncher Icon** option the image becomes clear.
Is there anyone has a solution?
[Action Bar and Tab Icon (Option)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMGwj.png)

[Luncher Icon (Option)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z22ae.png)

Comment: have You tried if it works inside Your code? Maybe it´s just a preview bug in AS. But You can also put the drawables by paste and copy inside Your drawable folder......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when I choose **Action Bar and Tab** Icon from the **Asset Type** dropdown
>   list I find the image is not clear and if I returned to the Luncher
>   Icon option the image becomes clear.

As it is clear, You can use **Launcher Icon** for choosing the application Launcher.which means, you can use it with default color i mean, that is available for **Launcher Icon** only.

And since you are using `Action Bar and Tab Icon` this options can be used for two colors.like dark theme and white.

The best option to use for that `Button` is, `Goto ImageAsset -> Launcher Icon -> check the ClipArt` to enabled and then you can use that image with any colors you want.

Or you can simply use: [Android Drawable Importer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658?pr=idea)

Comment: ok, then how can I add an icon to drawable folder but with its true color? because when i choose luncher option the icon is added to mimap folder

Comment: Use that plugin, it is simple to use and has a lot of options to do that.

Comment: Good to heard that, also if you are looking for just material design icons:https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7647?pr=idea this is also available on both.goodluck

Answer (score 0):

Your png image is converted to white color since you choose "Holo Dark" theme. 
This [link](http://tools.android.com/recent/assetstudiointegration) explains more details how Assets Studio works as well as how the image is converted when you choose "Action bar and tab icon" option.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have typically seen this achieved is by dragging the image resource into the drawable folder, and specifying which pixel density folder you wish it to be placed into. Then, you can point to the specific drawable in code by using either it's int value:

```
R.drawable.icon_luncher
```

or by retrieving a drawable object directly:

```
Actionbar actionBar = getActionBar();

//requires valid context

if (actionBar!=null){

Drawable tabIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.icon_lunch)

actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("my tab")
                     .setIcon(tabIcon)
                     .setTabListener(this));
}
```

I would say to try using Toolbar instead of actionbar. It's much more functional than it's Actionbar predecessor, and can work similarly like so:

```
Toolbar toolBar = (ToolBar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
//check if null
if(actionBar!=null){
//add actionbar functionality here
}
```